# How to deep link on Huawei devices?

Tags: android, deep-linking, huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers, android-deep-link

With this intent filter, devices with google services offer the option of opening a link in an application or in a browser. Huawei devices open directly in the browser.

How to make earn a deep link on Huawei?

```
<intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
         <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
         <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
         <!-- Accepts URIs that begin with "http://www.example.com/gizmos” -->
         <data android:scheme="http"
               android:host="www.example.com" />
     </intent-filter>
```

Comment: Opening an link in an app should be independent of Google Services and also work on Google free devices.

Comment: any update on that? i'm facingsame issue

Comment: @MoustafaEL-Saghier The deep link from the huawei mail application did not work for me, otherwise everything is fine

Comment: i'm looking for solution for deep link from notifications it's not triggering at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code that you provided above can also be directly used on Huawei devices.

You can also refer to huawei [push kit](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/hms/huawei-pushkit/):

```
<activity android:name=".DeeplinkActivity">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <data
            <!-- Customize the following information:-->
            android:host="com.huawei.codelabpush"
            android:path="/deeplink"
            android:scheme="pushscheme" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

For more details, check [Docs link](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-Guides/andorid-basic-clickaction-0000001087554076#section20203190121410).

Comment: but I do not need notifications, the user must follow the link, for example, from the letter and open it in the application

Comment: hi@Денис,May i ask in what scenario you have a problem? I posted the above link to show that Deeplink works properly on Huawei phones.

Comment: I received an email containing a link. when I click on this link, I want to choose to open it in the app or in the browser. But Huawei immediately opens it in the browser and does not offer to select an application.

Comment: @Денис The answer shows what is missing in your definition: the attribute `android:path="/deeplink"`